# Youtube and Google Pages Not Loading in Google Chrome? (giving weird symbols)

Tags: google-chrome

https://youtube.com
and
https://google.co.uk

Is now equal to:

> ��
>    E  ��b���� I � v���n/�] 
>   z)�Ĉq$�j�d�ɞ���Z�B�33H_ 
>   z K7��c 3�t���bA��� <��j�N�ef� �Q� y�B0��d0�����?Ј
>   N�ܾ��l� ��{c *���^](��>� �`�c��S��4 
>   d] ¬�  ���?�  � f�{����A�y��D�c��i4����p�+4�6k���� 
>   ��� �Tb�*#{��0��0�cv��j����т� ��S޺�  � ��! �n��onG�  ��Y@C
>   PG Lh8 �# �� � � '�bn� g�� ��������0���n̨v���Y��{ H�'�s���4���s�� _ڴ� ���͛� �'�y�wp���ظ��_� (]����Ͳ��׏�J �fy�,�8M���ټ��.'N�{����@ A�� s���$�Wa% ��$���(~8���(�a����oѷXM��.�x�ʮ��>�z�J�8I�Ѣ 
>   @�W�4v��g� fΗ ǋ$٬�u �W�j�ƫ�ZQ�o�E��� ��a��F��d�@ M� ���Ș����E�F�j�LëU� %,�F/lp�����X@�� �u���¼ Ŗ��7+�3��}
>   "g��\P� �]�\I��pB��Ę�dU�q# f��CQ �a���I�� PG�?��C`pL��iَ����^����I�3Wջ�j�i {�vo�X� ��

I trimmed that down a lot.

I use Windows 10,  I "reset chrome", and have Norton.

The only way to watch youtube is through the extremely slow Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/7uwL_DP8n0A/id3mqMsEAwAJ) product forum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! I (after making a backup) deleted everything in the User Data folder in

> C:\Users\(Name)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

That cleared everything up! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the [Chrome Character Encoding Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/set-character-encoding/bpojelgakakmcfmjfilgdlmhefphglae)

And try to change page encoding to UTF-8 or Page Default.

Comment: Sorry I haven't got time to comment on this post (very busy), But it still doesn't work. Tried all of the encoding options...

Comment: Has no one else had this problem? It still persists for me...